# Binding and support for rich text formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, .net-4.5

Consider the following scenario:

- I have a `ListView` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection` using the `DataContext`:

  ```xml
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  ```

  The `class` containing the `string` data uses the `DependencyProperty` mechanism to keep the displayed content synced with the data collection.
- The `ListView` has one column that is editable (I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-3-in-place-edit) to achieve this); the `ListViewItem` is then either a `TextBlock` or a `TextBox`. This is done using a `DataTemplate` and two `Style` resources.
- I'd like to format the string displayed in the `TextBlock` based on a search string. Specifically, I'd like to format the items of the `ListView` to become bold as the user types in their search query if there is a match (only the characters that match in sequence should be made bold). This only needs to be displayed for the text currently being rendered using the `TextBlock` (that is, text not currently being edited).

I've considered using an `IMultiValueConverter` that takes in a reference to the `TextBlock` that renders the data so that I can format the text appropriately. However, this will destroy the binding that I've set up:

```xml
<TextBlock.Text>
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource searchFormatter}" ConverterParameter="{x:Reference Name=txtSearch}">
    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
      <Binding Path="NameOfBoundDependencyProperty"/>
      <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
  </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

`searchFormatter` being the `IMultiValueConverter` and `txtSearch` being the `TextBox` containing the search query.

I'm still learning WPF so I'm not familiar with the best approach or to what's possible. Is there a way to keep the data bound (so that edits reflect in the collection and the `ListView`) and still represent the data differently to the user (so that search matches may be bold)? Perhaps it would be cleaner if I manage the binding manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a `Control` that supports HTML so that I could use an `IValueConverter` to update the value of the displayed text on the fly without affecting any active bindings. I used the code from [here](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2010/08/31/a-rich-html-textblock-for-wpf.aspx) and modified it so that it looked like a `TextBlock` within my `ListView`:

```cs
BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
SelectionBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
Background = Brushes.Transparent;
```

However, I still needed to trigger the `IValueConverter` so that the display is updated as the user types in their search query (code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4489086/1244630)):

```cs
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemsSource);
view.Refresh();
```

I didn't want to slow down the search process so I only forced this refresh if there was actually a match (or if the state of having a match moves to no match). My `IValueConvertor` simply inserted the bold tags to match the search query:

```xml
<RichTextBox Text="{Binding Path=DisplayItem, Converter={StaticResource searchFormatter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference txtSearch}}"/>
```

Where `searchFormatter` this time is an `IValueConvertor`.