# WPF: Reset ListView selected index after items refreshed

Tags: wpf, listview, code-behind

I have an ListView defined in XAML, and it's ItemsSource is set code-behind. ItemsSource is not a property, so I dont want bind it to observable collection. 
To update GUI I call *ListView.Items.Refresh()* method after selected index was changed (I do some work on selection changed and list view items are display the result). 
After that two situations may occurs:

- if I change selected item of ListView by mouse, selected index is changed right and stay in its place after Refresh() method was called;
- if I change selected item by arrows up and down on keyboard, selected index is always jumps to first item.

My question is what may I do to make selected item index of ListView right after selected item was changed by keyboard and items were refreshed in code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **SelectionChanged** event why dont you try **MouseLeftButtonDown** event and **KeyDown** event.

This will solve your issue.

Snippet as follow,

```
private void lst_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            item = lst.SelectedItem;
            fnTask();
        }

        private void lst_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            item = lst.SelectedItem;
            fnTask();
        }
        private void fnTask()
        {
            lst.Items.Refresh();
            lst.SelectedItem = item;
        }
```

Comment: I dont understand, what the diffetence? Your code produces the same result, I think. I'll check this of cource and notify You. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4489112/964478