# Pass Selected Items from ListBox into viewmodel and delete them?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

In my code I have a listbox where I select items with checkbox inside it and question is how to pass this items to viewmodel and delete them from listbox

Here is my Xaml Code with listbox

```
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ColumnHeaderBorder}" CornerRadius="7" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="#FFFFFF" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"  Grid.RowSpan="2" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding TechTabList}"  Margin="5"
            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="TechListBox">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="50" Width="auto">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="800"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="0,0,0,-1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource NeonColor}" Opacity="1"/>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" >
                        <Viewbox Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <CheckBox  Style="{StaticResource CheckBox}" Margin="0,0,3,0" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}"/>
                        </Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
```

Here is my viewmodel with Command where I need to delete selected Items

```
   ArchiveTable = new RelayCommand(_ArchiveTable);   
    }

    private void _ArchiveTable()
    {
        //Here foreach on selecteditems but how to pass them here 


    }
```

Comment: If you delete them from your TechTabList, they will be removed from the ListBox

Comment: Bind `CheckBox.IsChecked` to a property of item inside `TechTabList` (call it `IsChecked`), then in viewmodel you can use linq `TechTabLists.Where(item => item.IsChecked)` to get all checked items.

Comment: Your `RelayCommand` needs to expect `Action<object>` then, in your Command Binding, you would pass the selected items as a `CommandParameter`. Something like `<Button Content="Archive this table" Command="{Binding ArchiveTable}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TechListBox, Path=SelectedItems}"/>`. There is a catch when it comes to using Selected Items, when user selects one item, then the `SelectedItems` is populated (if bound), when user selects more than one ,that's when `SelectedItems` are populated, keep that in mind.

Comment: @XAMlMAX and after  that can i use foreach on this elements to delete them ?

Comment: Yes, you will have exactly what `ListBox` considers selected items. You can then remove them from underlying collection, in your case `TechTabList`. Make sure your Collection notifies about changes to its items though, for that use `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: @XAMlMAX what must be inside this foreach becouse I tried and got does not exist in the current context

Comment: You need to update your question I don't know what you're doing with the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

ListBox has a property SelectedItems. Bind it, as all other properties from your view model. 
[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems?view=netframework-4.8)

Then you need to remove items from binded list, and refresh UI. I would do it by ObservableColletion as source for ListView. [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488463/how-i-can-refresh-listview-in-wpf), I like the answer which tells about using INotifyCollectionChanged

Comment: `SelectedItems` is a `ReadOnly` property, you cannot bind to it. If you use `ObservableCollection` there is no need to manually update UI, that's what `ObservableCollection` is for.

Comment: " there is no need to manually update UI" well looks like I did not write it clear :) I am aware of what you mean, ObservableCollectio is a solution

Answer (score 0):

Because `SelectedItems` is a `ReadOnly` property, you can't bind directly to it.
In order to remove those items from the list one would have to use a different type of a `RelayCommand`. Like this:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _execute;
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = (o) => true;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #region Implementation of ICommand

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute.Invoke(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute.Invoke(parameter);
        RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Once you have that, then you can utilise `CommandParamater` for Binding. Like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="TechTabList" ... />
<Button Content="Delete Selected Items" Command="{Binding ArchiveTable}" CommandParamater="{Binding ElementName=TechLabList, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
```

Now in your implementation of the command:

```
private void _ArchiveTable(object parameter)
{
    var items = (parameter as IList).Cast<YourTypeHere>();
    //now you can remove those from the collection
    foreach(...)
}
```